# setting bits in a 64bit int

Tags: c++

I am trying to set a set of bits in a 64 bit int to ones.
As you can see in the loop in main I'm setting bits 40 to 47 to 1 using the setBit function.
for a reason I don't understand bits 16 to 23 are also set to 1 as you can see from the program's output:
0000000011111111000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000
I couldn't mimic the same behavior on a regular int.
BTW I also tried using a unsigned long long instead of int64_t with the same problem.
What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

int64_t x = 0;

 void setBit(int64_t *num, int index)
{
 *num |= (1 << index);
}

bool retreiveBit(int64_t *num, int index)
{
 return *num & (1 << index);
}

int main()
{
 for (int i = 40; i < 48; ++i)
 setBit(&x, i);

 for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
 {
  int digit = retreiveBit(&x, i);
  cout << digit;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the sub-expression:

```
(1 << index)
```

the type of the constant `1` is `int`, so this shift is done in an `int`.  If your `int` isn't 64 bits wide (it probably isn't), then this shift has undefined behaviour.

You need to use a constant that is at least 64 bits wide:

```
(1LL << index)
```

(you need to do this in both the `setBit()` and `retrieveBit()` functions).

Comment: `index` is `int` as well.  Can that cause issues?

Comment: @Mr.Llama: No, it's fine - for the shift operators the promoted type of the left-hand operand is what matters.

Comment: better to use `1ULL` instead.